# Highcharts Bubble with csv data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want to create a bubble charts with highcharts by importing data from csv file, this the code what i do:

```
'$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
           zoomType: 'xy'
        },
          xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: true,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            endOnTick: true,

             max :2,
             min:-2,
             tickPixelInterval: 200,


        },yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            endOnTick: true,
             max :2,
             min: -2,
             tickPixelInterval: 150,

        },


        title: {
            text: 'Cycle 2012 Q 4'
        },

        series: [{

            data: [[0.612026169,1.57522991,0.2302]]
        }, {

            data: [[0.4410667,-0.96442802,0.1662]]
        }, {

            data: [[-0.280249839,-0.687351853,0.1553]]
        }, {

            data: [[0.518541583,0.045330936,0.1985]]
        }, {    

            data: [[0.098823319,0.164087324,0.2086]]
        }]

    });

});'
```

i don't know how can i have the same result with importing data from csv ?? can you help me? Thanx

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-csv.htm

Comment: How your CSV looks like?

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to preprocess the data before passing it to Highcharts. The tutorial covers it in this section: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file